# Python BeautifulSoup scraping; how to combine two different fields, or pair them based on location in site?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, scrape

Ok guys, so I'm very much a beginner here. The purpose of what I'm trying to do is to scrape a website for company names and corresponding phone numbers. The end goal would be to write these to a CSV that can be opened with Excel.

Currently I'm able to retrieve the company names, and the phone numbers, separately. I am thinking that i could merge the two lists somehow, but I'm concerned about a single outlier data offsetting the whole merge, and mismatching the numbers to names.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

```
from urllib import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.iqsdirectory.com/bolts/bolts-2/'
html = request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

data1 = soup.findAll('span', {'itemprop':'name'})
data2 = soup.findAll('a', {'itemprop':'telephone'})

datalist1 = []
datalist2 = []

for i in data1:
    datalist1.append(i.string)

for i in data2:
    datalist2.append(i.string)

x = zip(datalist1, datalist2)

print(list(x))
```

Is it possible to pull name and phone in the same soup function in order to preserve their connection?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Instead of getting a list of all names, and all telephone numbers. How about you get a list of the header element (h3 with class cname) which contains the name and number. Then for each of those header elements, you can parse a name and number (if it exists), and add it to the csv.

Comment: This is what I want to do, but don't know how.

Comment: I just wrote up a quick one. I hope you are able to understand it to apply for future solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    target = soup.select("h3.cname")
    with open("data.csv", 'w', newline="") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(["Name", "Phone"])
        for tar in target:
            name = tar.find("span", itemprop="name").text
            phone = tar.find("a", itemprop="telephone").text
            writer.writerow([name, phone])


main("https://www.iqsdirectory.com/bolts/bolts-2/")
```

Output: [view-online](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/0b7af45b8f8707bdb4fb81d59f9b25ed/data.csv)

[image]

Comment: This accomplishes everything I was trying to do... so much more swiftly. Thank you.

Comment: @ahmed I need some direction on trying to make this script work on all pages of its type.  Can you help or point me in the right direction of where to start? For axample, input iqsdirectory.com/category1 and have the program scrape from each of the pages listed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that fits your needs. If a name or number does not exist, it will not be represented in that list. There is probably a correct exception to catch but I don't know the correct name off the top of my head.

The idea is as I explained in my comment. I get a list of the headers. For each header, I try to find the name and number. If I can't find it, I catch the exception. If I can find it, I append it to a company. And then for each company, I append it to companies. Our result is a list of companies, where each company is a list containing a name and a number.

```
from urllib import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.iqsdirectory.com/bolts/bolts-2/'
html = request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

headers = soup.findAll('h3', {"class": 'cname'})
companies = []
for header in headers:
    company = []
    try:
        company.append(header.find('span', {'itemprop':'name'}).text)
    except Error as e:
        print(e)
        pass
    try:
        company.append(header.find('a', {'itemprop':'telephone'}).text)
    except Error as e:
        print(e)
        pass
    companies.append(company)
print(companies)
```

Your result is:

```
[['A & J Fastener Corp.', '877-563-2658'], ['AA Anchor Bolt, Inc.', '800-929-3845'], ['Abbott-Interfast Corporation', '800-877-0789'], ['Accurate Manufactured Products Group, Inc.', '317-472-9000'], ['ACF Components & Fasteners, Inc.', '800-824-5449'], ['Aerospace Manufacturing Corporation', '973-472-2300'], ['Aetna Screw Products Co.', '847-647-9555'], ['AFT Fasteners', '877-844-8595'], ['AJ Fasteners Inc.', '714-630-1556'], ['All-Ways Fasteners, Inc.', '800-870-0372'], ['Amco Enterprises', '866-651-2626'], ['American Bolt Corp.', '262-786-6530'], ['Anchor Bolt & Screw Company', '847-841-7000'], ['Anchor Bolt Source', '888-812-6587'], ['Ancrabec', '888-649-7203'], ['Armour Screw Company', '800-726-4563'], ['Aspen Fasteners', '800-479-0056'], ['Assembly Products, Inc.', '608-296-1666'], ['Associated Fastening Products, Inc.', '888-696-0709'], ['Atwood Industries', '800-362-2059'], ['B&G Manufacturing', '800-366-3067'], ['Baco Enterprises, Inc.', '800-622-2226'], ['Barnhill Bolt Co., Inc.', '800-472-3900'], ['Birmingham Fastener Manufacturing', '800-695-3511'], ['Blue Ribbon Fastener Co.', '847-673-1248'], ['BMB Fasteners, Inc.', '973-256-4010'], ['Bolt Products, Inc.', '800-423-6503'], ['Bossard North America, Inc.', '800-772-2738'], ['Bowie Bolt & Supply, Inc.', '800-337-9650'], ['British Metrics', '800-762-5134'], ['Brunner Manufacturing Co., Inc.', '608-847-6667'], ['Buckeye Fasteners, Inc.', '800-437-1689'], ['C&L Rivet Company, Inc.', '215-672-1113'], ['Cal-Fasteners, Inc.', '714-854-1715'], ['California Bolt Co.', '714-957-6000'], ['Champion Bolt & Supply', '425-339-2632'], ['Chicago Hardware & Fixture Company', '847-455-6609'], ['Chicago Nut & Bolt', '888-529-8600'], ['Circle Bolt & Nut Co., Inc.', '800-548-2658'], ['Coburn-Myers Fastening Systems Incorporated', '800-662-7459'], ['Connor Fastener', '478-742-7261'], ['Cordova Bolt, Inc.', '800-421-3435'], ['DAN-LOC Bolt & Gasket', '800-231-6355'], ['Dayton Nut & Bolt Co., Inc.', '888-711-2658'], ['Deco Manufacturing Company', '800-637-5861'], ['Delta Fastener Corp.', '800-670-5938'], ['Diamond Fasteners', '877-729-6283'], ['Dyson Corporation', '800-680-3600'], ['E & T Fasteners', '800-650-4707'], ['East Coast Metals, Inc.', '800-355-2060'], ['Eastwood Manufacturing', '281-447-0081'], ['EBC Industries', '814-456-4287'], ['Elgin Equipment Group', '630-434-7200'], ['Elgin Fastener Group', '812-689-8990'], ['Engineered Components Company', '847-841-7000'], ['EPS Engineered Parts Sourcing Inc.', '877-889-1017'], ['Falcon Fastening Solutions', '502-266-6292'], ['FASCO, Inc.', '708-371-0747'], ['Fast-Rite International, Inc.', '888-327-8077'], ['Fastenal Company', '507-454-5374'], ['Fastener Dimensions, Inc.', '800-969-2188'], ['Fastener Solutions, Inc.', '866-463-2910'], ['Fastener SuperStore, Inc.', '866-688-2500'], ['Fastener Tool & Supply, Inc.', '800-662-9232'], ['Fasteners Plus International', '708-479-5558'], ['Fasteners Unlimited, Inc.', '724-776-7273'], ['Fastening Products of Lancaster, Inc.', '717-299-5771'], ['FM Stainless Fasteners', '800-749-1115'], ['Genesis Bolt & Supply', '866-276-1399'], ['Global Certified Fastener', '708-450-9301'], ['Global Fastener & Supply, Inc.', '800-785-2664'], ['Guidon Corporation', '856-866-8808'], ['Haydon Bolts, Inc.', '215-537-8700'], ['Hayes Bolt & Supply', '619-231-5966'], ['HC Pacific', '909-598-0509'], ['Hercules Fasteners', '800-332-7320'], ['Hudson Fasteners, Inc.', '877-427-2739'], ['Hydra-Dynamics, Inc.', '936-273-2882'], ['Infinity Fasteners', '913-438-2252'], ['IntegraTECH Distribution', '603-880-3760'], ['J.P. Ruklic Screw Company', '708-339-3600'], ['K-T Bolt Manufacturing, Inc.', '800-553-4521'], ['KelKo Products Company', '800-346-7883'], ['Kinter', '800-323-2389'], ['Lamons Fastener Division', '713-673-5376'], ['Lamons Gasket Company', '800-231-6906'], ['Larson Hardware Manufacturing Company', '815-625-0503'], ['Lincoln Structural Solutions', '402-952-4400'], ['Master Bolt Manufacturing, Inc.', '888-905-2658'], ['Melfast, Inc', '973-227-0045'], ['Micro Plastics, Inc', '(870)453-2261'], ['Mid-States Bolt & Screw Co.', '800-482-0867'], ['Mutual Screw & Supply', '800-222-0324'], ['National Bolt & Nut Corporation', '630-307-8800'], ['Nickel Systems, Inc.', '215-855-5633'], ['Nord-Lock / Superbolt®, Inc.', '412-279-1149'], ['Norwood Screw Machine Parts', '800-437-6644'], ['Nova Fasteners Co. Inc.', '877-541-7222'], ['O.E.M. Fastening Systems', '800-928-7439'], ['O.E.M. Hardware', '800-663-6554'], ['Ocean State Stainless, Inc.', '800-394-6396'], ['Palmer Bolt & Supply Co.', '(937)778-9606'], ['Parker Fasteners', '623-925-5998'], ['PennEngineering®', '800-342-5736'], ['Pohl Spring Works, Inc.', '800-777-1284'], ['Product Components Corporation', '800-336-0406'], ['Production Materials Inc.', '224-434-2290'], ['R&R Engineering Company Inc.', '800-979-1921'], ['Reco Industries', '636-639-6010'], ['Remco Bolt', '800-460-3327'], ['ROBNET', '410-247-7273'], ['SASCO Fasteners', '800-779-2024'], ['SC Fastening Systems, LLC.', '330-468-3300'], ['Screw Products International', '800-876-5153'], ['Secure Fastener & Tool Company', '201-939-4422'], ['Specialty Bolt & Screw, Inc.', '413-789-6700'], ['Specialty Screw Corporation', '815-969-4100'], ['St. Louis Screw & Bolt', '800-237-7059'], ['Stalcop', '765-436-7926'], ['Stanley Industries Inc.', '800-253-2658'], ['Stelfast® Inc.', '800-729-9779'], ['Suncor Stainless, Inc.', '800-394-2222'], ['Sunny Screw Industry Co. Ltd.', '770-351-2858'], ['Tanner Bolt & Nut Corp.', '800-456-2658'], ['Tengco', '714-676-8200'], ['The Federal Group', '800-759-2658'], ['Tripac', '951-280-4488'], ['TSA Manufacturing', '800-228-2948'], ['United Titanium, Inc.', '844-321-4684'], ['USP Aerospace Solutions, Inc.', '631-287-6321'], ['Valtra, Inc.', '800-989-5244'], ['Wayne Bolt & Nut Company', '800-521-2207'], ['WINK Fasteners, Inc.', '804-966-8111'], ['Wodin, Inc.', '440-439-4222'], ['Wurth Industry', '800-428-4686'], ['Yangtze Railroad Materials', '855-889-2648']]
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you!